# How to maintain proportion on max width and fixed height?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, aspect-ratio

I am trying to make [something like this](http://demo.codestag.com/ink/). The top image is 100% width of the browser but shorter than `100%`height of the browser, so the content peeks up a little bit ( the tops of the two images below are showing ).

Also, when the brower size is scaled, it maintains it's aspect ratio and the two images always show unless the responsive breaking point `@media only screen and (min-width:768px)` has all of the images stack on top of eachother.

Here is my css:

```
.thumb-12 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.thumb-12 img {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height:700px;
    background-position:center center;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
}
```

this works well until it gets passed `1500px` or so width wise, then it starts to stretch the image.

Is this possible to do with pure css?

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense applying a background to an `img` tag. Apply this directly to your container (which seems to be `thumb-12`) and remove the img tag.

```
.thumb-12 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;

    background: url('your_image.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Please note that the parent of this element must have a determined height if you want `height: 100%;` to work on all browsers (except if **all** parents have the same property, until `body`).

Comment: @Sabastian That maybe the case, but I think you are mis-understanding the question. I need it to have a maxium height and retain it's proportions.

Comment: Your element width must keep the proportion or the background only ?

Comment: please look at this http://demo.codestag.com/ink/. I am trying to shorten the top image so the tops of the bottom two images are visible. In other words...100%width and 700px height or so while maintaining aspect ratio when browser stretches above 1500px.

Comment: Like I said, background image will keep the proportion itself. I edited my answer to set a fixed height. Actually, if you want your image to stretch beyond 1500px, use a 1500px-wide image. `cover` property makes the image adapt till it takes all the space. If your div goes beyond 1500 and your image is 1500 too, it will stretches like a desktop background.

Answer (score 0):

I added a wrapper div around the image div, and gave it `overflow:hidden` and the fixed height of `700px;` while keeping the height of the actual image `100%;`

```
.thumb-wrapper {
    max-height: 700px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.thumb-12 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.thumb-12 img {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-position:center center;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
}
```